# cannot use proper named parameter in flutter app

Tags: flutter, named-parameters

[image]

yes, i did just do that.

the trouble i have is that i can't remove the red underline, and thus my project won't run.
InputDecoration error parameter : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/error.html

defintely exists .. the other named parameters work.

I'll leave it at this. It's quite straightforward ! and nothing to help me elsewhere online .. yes, i tried flutter doctor, clean, whatever.

Comment: Hover on `error`. What does the error message say?

Comment: You're using an older version of Flutter where that `error` property has not existed yet. [This is the commit](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/8d837062a4470867718060e006f45b4a767c0461) where they added this `error` property to `InputDecoration`.

Comment: Use `errorText` inside the InputDecoration.